# Trim monitor output (because of dead pixels)

Tags: xrandr, output, resolution

I searched a lot and finally came here to ask my question.

Recently my screen got damaged and now has some rows of dead pixels. They are located at the very top of the screen and making it very difficult to read for example the url of a website.

So I wondered if it would be possible to set the output from 1680x1050 to 1680x950 and just don't use the first 100 pixels that were damaged?

[image: Photo of screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just select the pixels that are undamaged, stem reworks don't work like that, unfortunately. If you change the resolution it will reduce the quality of the entire screen's display  itself. But the screen can be replaced if it is a flat monitor or a laptop.

Comment: I am aware of the possibility of buying a new screen. But I thought I could still use it because not all of it is broken.But it's just my second screen so I will have to accept the broken pixels..

Answer (score 5):

Pardon for reviving a dead thread but in short, yes, it is possible!
I think I figured out *finally* how to use [`xrandr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr).

I used [`umc`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/umc/) - universal modeline calculator to compute mode lines but the same can be achieved with `cvt` and `gtf`. It shouldn't really matter with LCD displays.

Here are the steps to cut the top 100px of the display. Change the resolution according to your setup.

1. `umc 1920 980 60`

   Output:

```
  # 1920x980x60.00 @ 61.080kHz
  Modeline "1920x980x60.00"  156.364800  1920 2032 2240 2560  980 984 988 1018  -HSync +VSync
```

2. `xrandr --newmode SMOL 156.364800  1920 2032 2240 2560  980 984 988 1018  -HSync +VSync`
3. `xrandr --addmode eDP-1 SMOL`
4. `xrandr --output eDP-1 --fb 1920x980 --panning 1920x980 --mode SMOL`
5. `xrandr --fb 1920x980 --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --transform 1,0,0,0,1,-100,0,0,1 --panning 1920x980 --fb 1920x980`

Note that I used `--fb` before and after output. Strangely, only then moved the 'viewport' to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: An example describing how you'd "edit the viewport with xrandr" would go a long ways towards making this a better answer. Feel free to incorporate the AU post, with attribution, if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for pushing for a better answer, Jeff! But what does 'AU post' stand for?

Comment: Thank *you* for *making* a better answer! My apologies for the AU abbreviation; it is short for "Ask Ubuntu" -- the link you posted: https://askubuntu.com/a/1177060/784098

Comment: Gotcha! Now I need to solve the same on an external monitor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Unfortunately I don't have access to a computer for a couple of weeks (writing this on my phone). As soon as I get home I'll try it out and accept the answer.

Comment: No hurry, no worry. Same thing with the solution, only 4 years late :)